PDF formatting from Google Sheets
I have a google sheet that needs to be filled out whenever a piece of inventory is rejected.
I currently have some Apps Script code that creates a button to generate a pdf when it is finished.
I cannot figure out how to reconfigure the PDF so that the sheet fills the entire pdf page, rather than merely sitting in the center.
Here are screen shots of the sheet, the code, and the resulting pdf.
So my question is, how do I adjust the size of content in a pdf via apps scripts?


function tryAsPDF() {
  // Get the active spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // Get the name of the spreadsheet
  var spreadsheetName = spreadsheet.getName();
  
  // Get the ID of the spreadsheet
  var spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId();
  
  // Get the current date to use in the filename
  var currentDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
  
  // Construct the PDF file name
  var pdfFileName = spreadsheetName + "_" + currentDate + ".pdf";
  
  try {
    // Generate the PDF blob
    var pdfBlob = spreadsheet.getAs('application/pdf');
    
    // Get the destination folder by ID
    var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1jTbrFZyRGLQhoFMjhRbH1ID_bi_xgGoH");
    
    // Save the PDF to the destination folder
    var pdfFile = destinationFolder.createFile(pdfBlob);
    
    // Rename the PDF file
    pdfFile.setName(pdfFileName);
    
    Logger.log("PDF saved successfully.");
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error saving PDF: " + error);
  }
}

